# How to set the field can be null when there is relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship, one-to-many

I have an issue, when I delete a contractor that relate to that one residence, there will be an error something like `trying to get property name` in this line in index view `<li>Contractor: {{$res->contractor->name}}`. I want to make it possible by deleting the contractor, then the contractor field in residence view could be empty or null. And this can be vice versa. How can I do that? Here is my model.

**Residential.php**

```
class Residential extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name','res_code','postcode','city','state','image','contractor_id'];

    public function contractor()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contractor::class);
    }

    public function buyer()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Buyer::class);
    }
}
```

**Contractor.php**

```
class Contractor extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'contractors';
    protected $fillable = ['name','address','phone_no','email','avatar'];

    public function residential()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Residential::class);
    }

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(User::class, 'typable');
    }
}
```

Here is my controller.

**ResidentialController.php**

```
class ResidentialController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $contractor = Contractor::find($request->id);
        $residential = Residential::all();
        return view('residentials.index',compact('residential','contractor'));
    }
```

**ContractorController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
       $residential = Residential::find($request->id);
       $contractor = Contractor::all();
       return view('admins.contractors.index', compact('residential', 'contractor'));       
    }
```

And here is my view.

**residentials\index.blade.php**

```
@foreach($residential as $res)
<div class="panel-body">
   <ul class="list-unstyled list-justify">
       <li>ID: {{$res->id}}</li>
       <li>Code: {{$res->res_code}}</li>
       <li>Postcode: {{$res->postcode}}</li>
       <li>City: {{$res->city}}</li>
       <li>State: {{$res->state}}</li>
       <li>Contractor: {{$res->contractor->name}}
   </ul>
</div>
@endforeach
```

**contractors\index.blade.php**

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="contractor-table">
  <tr>
     <th>ID</th>
     <th>Company</th>
     <th>Phone No</th>
     <th>Email</th>
     <th>Residence</th>
     <th>Action</th>
  </tr>

@foreach($contractor as $cont)
   <tr class="contractor{{$cont->id}}">
       <td>{{$cont->id}}</td>
       <td><a href="/contractor/{{$cont->id}}/profile">{{$cont->name}}</a></td>
       <td>{{$cont->phone_no}}</td>
       <td>{{$cont->email}}</td>
       <td>{{$cont->residential->pluck('name')->implode(', ')}}</td>
@endforeach
</table>
```

I hope there is someone can understand my problem and can help me.

Comment: normally you would check if relationship data exists before displaying any attribute from it

Comment: `{{ optional($res->contractor)->name ?? 'n/a' }}`

Comment: Thank you @Tpojka that is the easier one I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` in your query.Using of it you will automatic receive `NULL` value.

The SQL LEFT JOIN returns all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table. This means that if the ON clause matches 0 (zero) records in the right table; the join will still return a row in the result, but with NULL in each column from the right table.

This means that a left join returns all the values from the left table, plus matched values from the right table or NULL in case of no matching join predicate.

***Reference link :*** [https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm#:~:text=Advertisements,column%20from%20the%20right%20table](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-left-joins.htm#:%7E:text=Advertisements,column%20from%20the%20right%20table).